# Link to item in the Email from another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow

i have a small request in workflow. what i am trying to do is to create a new item in  list B as an item in created in list A. I have to send an email as an item is created in list A and i have to send the link and id of the List A and List B.
I know how to get the item link of List A but i am facing problem in order to give url link to another list items edit form.
This is my workflow
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to construct the other list item's edit form URL

First you add the site URL,
 Select `workflow context` as a data source and `current site URL`  as field from source

[image]


[image]


Now you'll need to write the second part of the URL `/lists/yourListName/EditForm.aspx?ID=`you can take this part from the item edit form URL


[image]


Last part is adding the newly created item `ID`

1. Add a new lookup and select `your other list name` as the data source
2. Select `ID` as field from source
3. In the find list item section, select `GUID` field
4. In the `Value` select your `Create Item in` action output parameter.

[image]

**the result will be something like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you use the action"Create list item"  in your workflow, a variable named create appears in the action. The action also has the output clause which is denoted by **Variable:Create1**

At the workflow's run time, the variable create1 stores the list item ID of the item that is created in the other list.

Use this variable to generate the edit form link.

Comment: could you please provide me as to how should i get the id of the item.